# Audience Exclusion Script for Value in sendable Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, send-email

I'm trying to use "Audience Exclusion Script" for a send to a data extension where I want to exclude subscribers based on an attribute in the data extension I'm sending to.

Data Extension Field Name: `BMP: TC-Permission Privacy`

Type: `Boolean`

Exclusion Script: `[BMP: TC-Permission Privacy] == "False"`

The send works until I insert this script.

Can someone tell me where the mistake is or if it is even possible to use this without a separate data extension/list to compare against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this -- assuming that this `BMP: TC-Permission Privacy` column is part of your sending Data Extension.

The [AttributeValue()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#attributevalue) function will handle the case if the column doesn't exist:

```
AttributeValue("BMP: TC-Permission Privacy") == "FALSE" OR empty(AttributeValue("BMP: TC-Permission Privacy"))
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, that worked as suggested (even without the OR clause)!